# Picking out the id of an image embedded in a form from multiple forms to display back to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm building a profile page where I have to display a user's profile pic as well as 3 other pictures that he/she had previously selected. Now I'm passing into the view a "ProfileViewModels" viewmodel which contains two other viewmodels: of which one of them is a list of a viewmodel.

My images all display correctly. Each image is contained in a bootstrap card class of which contains two buttons; delete and update for each image in the card. Now, I'm surrounding each button with a form tag and embedding a hidden field that contains the id of each image so that when the user clicks on 'delete' or 'update' for a particular card which contains an image, it passes on the id of the selected image back to the controller needed for deletion.

However, on running my code, whenever I click on 'delete' or 'update' I'm getting null values in my controller and as such, I can't delete nor update my picture. Below are my viewmodels, cshtml view page and controller.

VIEMODEL INJECTED INTO THE VIEWPAGE:

```
public class ProfileViewModels
{
    public List<PicturesViewModel> Pictures { get; set; }
    public ProfilePicViewModel ProfilePic { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ProfilePicViewModel
{
    public string PictureId { get; set; }
    public string PictureAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IFormFile Picture { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class PicturesViewModel
{
    public string PictureId { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public IFormFile PictureForm { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(140, ErrorMessage = "picture description should not be more than 140 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

```
@model ProfileViewModels

@{
    var imgAddresses = new List<string>();
    var imgIds = new List<string>();
 }

@{ var path = "~/images/" + Model.ProfilePic.PictureAddress; }

@foreach (var pic in Model.Pictures)
{
    imgAddresses.Add(pic.Picture);
    imgIds.Add(pic.PictureId);
}

<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-3 mb-5">
        <img asp-append-version="true" src=@(path) alt="User Profile pic" class="rounded-circle" width="150" height="150" />
    </div>
    <!---other codes --->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body m-0">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pictures.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="card d-inline-block mr-1 mb-3" style="width: 31%;">
                <img src="~/images/@(imgAddresses[i])" alt="user_pictures" class="card-img-top" width="200" height="150" />
                <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">@Model.Pictures[i].Description</p>
                @using (HtmlHelperFormExtensions.BeginForm(Html, "DeletePicture", "User", FormMethod.Post, imgIds[i]))
                {
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
                    <input type="text" hidden value="@Model.Pictures[i].PictureId" />
                    <input type="text" hidden value="@(imgIds[i])" />
                    <button type="submit" class="card-link btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                }
                @using (HtmlHelperFormExtensions.BeginForm(Html, "AddPicture", "User", FormMethod.Post, imgIds[i]))
                {
                     <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
                     <input type="text" hidden value="@Model.Pictures[i].PictureId" />
                     <input type="text" hidden value="@(imgIds[i])" />
                     <button type="submit" class="card-link btn btn-outline-success">Update</button>
                }
                </div>
                </div>
                    }
                }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPicture(ProfileViewModels model)
{
    //code block for performing action
    RedirectToAction("Profile");
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePicture(ProfileViewModels model)
{
    //code block for performing action
    RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> `<input type="text" hidden value="@Model.Pictures[i].PictureId" />`

Please note that if the `name` attribute of the input field is omitted, the value of the input field within a `<form>` will not be sent at all.

> `imgIds.Add(pic.PictureId);`

In your code we can find that you populate `List<string> imgIds` with `PictureId(s)` you passed through view model, so `<input type="text" hidden value="@(imgIds[i])" />` might be same as `<input type="text" hidden value="@Model.Pictures[i].PictureId" />`.

> when the user clicks on 'delete' or 'update' for a particular card which contains an image, it passes on the id of the selected image back to the controller needed for deletion.

To pass the selected image's id to controller for deletion, you can try to modify the code as below.

*Specify `name="SelectedPictureId"` for hidden field*

```
@using (HtmlHelperFormExtensions.BeginForm(Html, "DeletePicture", "User", FormMethod.Post, imgIds[i]))
{
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="SelectedPictureId" value="@Model.Pictures[i].PictureId" />
    <button type="submit" class="card-link btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
}
```

*DeletePicture action method*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePicture(string SelectedPictureId)
{
    //code block for performing action
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

Besides, this article explains what model binding is and how it works, you can refer to it for detailed information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0